# How to implement a ram-lak filter in 1D fourier transform?

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, fft

Having a non-mathematical background I'm trying to understand how to implement filtering of data in the frequency domain as part of FFT. A javascript implementation of a discrete FFT is found here:
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#JavaScript

I am having trouble understanding how to implement a Ram-Lak filter such as the one found in fig 3 in this article:
http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~mueller/teaching/cse377/lab3.pdf

So far I have completed a FFT of an array of say 100 real numbers and obtained two resulting arrays with real and imaginary components, respectively of the 100 resulting frequency components from 0 frequency (DC) to 99.

After obtaining this result i do this (in pseudocode):

center = frequencies.length/2

For n = frequencies 1 to 99 in result of FFT do {

If (n < center) {Multiply each real and imaginary  component by (n/(center))}

If (n >= center) { Multiply each real and imaginary  component by (frequencies.length-n/center)}

} // end do

Perform inverse FFT

After the inverse FFT the 100 real initial numbers should have been run through a Ram-lak filter - am I corrrect?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709871/matlab-how-to-implement-a-ram-lak-filter-ramp-filter-in-the-frequency-domain).

Comment: Hi, 
I have been away for the last few days, hence the delay. Thank you for pointing my attention to the mathlab entry. However, I'm not proficient in mathlab code. Could you please elaborate on how the ram-lak filter is construted?