# Filtered BackProjection Matlab

Tags: matlab, imaging, tomography-reconstruction, back-projection

I have already implemented the code for BackProjection and it works.
Now I have to implement the code for the filtered version, using first ramlak filter and then hamming window.
My sinogram has dimension 144x180.
My idea is

```
filter=zeros(1,144)';

filter(1:73)=[0:1/72:1];

filter(74:end)=[1-1/72:-1/72:1/72];
```

in order to have an filter like this [image]

and then for each projection s

```
filtered_proj=fft(s).*filter;
proj=real(ifft(filtered_proj));
```

and then performing the backprojection algorithm

Could you please tell me if it is correct?

Thank you

Comment: If its not, you will see it as the result will be wrong. Try it. You can very easily find matlab code that does this, you can alway compare against that

Comment: @EdoardoDeGaspari: We don't answer open-ended questions like "Could you please tell me if my code is correct?" or "Could you please tell me if my math is correct?". You have identified what you need to implement. You have written your program. That's a great start. Please try it. Decide whether the result is what you expect. If not, ask the question accordingly but be sure to include your reasons as to why not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I asked if you could check my code, because in many codes, I saw that the ram-lak filter has been implemented in the opposite direction i.e highest values on the sides, and lowest value in the middle ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709871/matlab-how-to-implement-a-ram-lak-filter-ramp-filter-in-the-frequency-domain)  , and i don't know which one is wrong or which one is correct.